# call instruction don't works in asm block

Tags: assembly, call, builder

I'm trying to use the call statement within a block in asm Builder, but it does not work:

```
asm {
     (...)
    @arctan:
     call @tan
         cmp cx, is_radian
     jnz @esta_convertido
     call @to_degree
@esta_convertido:
     fld1
     fpatan
     fld CENTO_OITENTA
     fmul
     fldpi
     fdiv
     ret
(...)
```

}

Errors:
E2451 Undefined symbol '@to_degree'

E2451 Undefined symbol 'void'

E2329 Invalid combination of opcode and operands

Comment: seriously i see no @tan defined here :D

Comment: Ops, I copy the wrong error! Sorry, but is E2451 Undefined symbol '@to_degree'

Comment: the same question, you may provide '@to_degree' definition.

Comment: @to_degree already defined, but I don't write here. Thanks